# Mongo messy DOB string field to Age

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection with documents like:

```
{'state': 'NY', 'DOB': '2000-01-02'},
{'state': 'NY', 'DOB': '2002/03/04'},
{'state': 'NY', 'DOB': '00-00-00'},
{'state': 'NY', 'DOB': 'male'},
...
```

I want outputs like:

```
{'state': 'NY', 'DOB': '2000-01-02', 'Age': 21},
{'state': 'NY', 'DOB': '2002/03/04', 'Age': 19},
{'state': 'NY', 'DOB': '00-00-00', 'Age': None}, # or Mongo None equivalent
{'state': 'NY', 'DOB': 'male', 'Age': None}, # or Mongo None equivalent
...
```

I'm constructing aggregation queries in PyMongo, and I'm wondering if there's an aggregate way to try to convert a field to Mongo Date object and then extract `Age` from it, else (if a date cannot be extracted), return None. Some condition in the shell below?

```
def map_age(state, city)
    db.aggregate([
        {'$match': {
             'state': state,
             'DOB': {"$exists": True}, 
             'Age': {"$exists": False}
        }},
        {...}     
    ])
```

Comment: Why not do it in your code?

Comment: You can use [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) aggregate operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$let` to create variable for dob convert and do operation
- `$dateFromString` to convert in to date from string if its in valid then replace with "None"
- `$subtract` minus converted date from current date `$$NOW` you can use `new Date()` as well
- `$divide` above subtract date by "31536000000" means "365*24*60*60*1000"
- `$round` to round age number

```
db.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      Age: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            dob: {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$DOB",
                onError: "None"
              }
            }
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$dob", "None"] },
              "None",
              {
                $round: {
                  $divide: [
                    { $subtract: ["$$NOW", "$$dob"] },
                    31536000000 // 365*24*60*60*1000
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nPgz7DX_bN1)

Comment: I'm not sure this produces the desired result... e.g., returns standardized values like 0.0

Comment: Great answer. what will be the performance impact of using in combination with `$let` operation in comparison to just `$dateFromString`? Just curious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: performance will impact with any of the aggregation operators, not just only `$let`, so there is a mongodb rule of thumb you can add more fields or either it is ok with duplicate data in database with your required format but don't do more operations for just formatting query result... To handle rare case we can use these aggregation operators...

Comment: @turivishal this works after all — do you know how to implement it so that it actually updates all documents in the collection?

Comment: @turivishal never mind, resolved, thank you!

Comment: sorry i did not understand, i get it now, see update query [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BbVdmOhX_hy) i have added new field so it would be easy to verify correct date don't loose old data.

Comment: @turivishal one more conditional: is there a way to add a date extraction? For instance, if one DOB is "2020-02-02 *******", can we pass some interim replacement on that string to dateFromString?

Comment: there is a `$replaceAll`/`$replaceOne` operators to replace string by another sting,, so after replace you can convert before dateFromString.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @prasad_, you have to make use of the `$dateFromString` operator in either the `$project` or `$addFields` stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "age": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          dateString: "$DOB",
          onError: null,
          onNull: null,
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Would this appropriately handle both cases "YYYY-MM-DD" and "YYYY/MM/DD"?

Comment: Yes, it will.   https://mongoplayground.net/p/hWXrxNzYlCs